# mongodb date range filter error when document have array documents embebed

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have one problem with filter one date with a range in a array embebed on MongoDB.

Document 1:

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61d406681512ba17533b35c9"
    },
    "items": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61d406681512ba17533b35cd"
        },
        "bookingEnd": {
            "$date": "2022-04-22T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "bookingStart": {
            "$date": "2022-03-19T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61d406681512ba17533b35cd"
        },
        "bookingEnd": {
            "$date": "2022-07-22T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "bookingStart": {
            "$date": "2022-06-19T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    }],
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2022-01-04T08:33:44.958Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2022-01-04T08:33:44.958Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Document 2:

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61d407c41512ba17533b35f7"
    },
    "items": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61d407c41512ba17533b35fb"
        }
        "bookingEnd": {
            "$date": "2022-05-22T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "bookingStart": {
            "$date": "2022-04-19T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    }],
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2022-01-04T08:39:32.648Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2022-01-04T08:39:32.648Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Resume:

I have 2 documents:

1. Document 1 (2 elements on embebed array):

- items.0.bookingStart: "2022-03-19T00:00:00.000Z"
- items.1.bookingStart: "2022-06-19T00:00:00.000Z"

1. Document 1 (1 element on embebed array):

- items.0.bookingStart: "2022-04-19T00:00:00.000Z"

Mongo filter:

```json
{ 'items.bookingStart': { $gte: ISODate('2022-03-01T00:00:00.000Z'), $lte: ISODate('2022-03-30T00:00:00.000Z') } }
```

Mongoose filter:

```
  async findAll(params: AdminFilterOrderDto) {
    const {
      bookingStartInitial,
      bookingStartFinal,
    } = params;

    const filter = {
      'items.bookingStart': {
        $gte: bookingStartInitial,
        $lte: bookingStartFinal,
      },
    };

    return await this.orderModel.find(filter);
  }
```

Applied filters:

1. $gte: "2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"; $lte: "2022-02-30T00:00:00.000Z" (It doesn't show anything GOOD)
2. $gte: "2022-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"; $lte: "2022-03-30T00:00:00.000Z" (It show one document. GOOD)
3. $gte: "2022-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"; $lte: "2022-04-30T00:00:00.000Z" (**It show two documents. BAD. It should show one document.**)
4. $gte: "2022-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"; $lte: "2022-05-30T00:00:00.000Z" (**It show one document. BAD. It shouldn't show anything.**)
5. $gte: "2022-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"; $lte: "2022-06-30T00:00:00.000Z" (It show one document. GOOD)
6. $gte: "2022-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"; $lte: "2022-07-30T00:00:00.000Z" (It doesn't show anything. GOOD)

Filter 3 and 4 give the wrong response.

Any idea what's going on? Is it MongoDB bug or am I performing the query wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To compare date field values, both the MongoDB document field and the supplied input parameter data type must be the same. You can use the `$type` operator to find the document's field type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$elemMatch`

```
db.collection.find({
  items: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $and: [
        {
          "bookingStart": {
            $gte: {
              "$date": "2022-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bookingStart": {
            $lte: {
              "$date": "2022-04-30T00:00:00.000Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G95CCtyc4UZ)

Comment: @gil.newe Perfect! It would be great if you can accept this answer and give it a up vote.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't got 15 on reputation :cry: